# $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ and continuous in [a,b] expect from final number of points prove F integrability

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to prove that :

if $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$ and continuous in [a,b] except from a finite number of points in $[a,b]$ then $f$ integrability.

I started to create the prove but I got stuck.

**My prove**

$f$ is bounded therefore exists $A,B$ real numbers that:

$$A \leq f(x) \leq B$$

In order to proof that $f$ integrability, I need to show that:

$$S(P)-s(P)< \epsilon$$

Well, I got pretty stuck here, I tried a few directions, but none of them seems to get to the conclusion that $S(P)-s(P)<\epsilon$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I think  you mean "except from a finite number of points", is this correct?

Comment: @Alan Yes, Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ is continuous except at finitely many points. Call them $a_1,\ldots,a_k$ and let $a_0=a$ and $a_{k+1}=b$. Order the points so that $a=a_0\leq a_1\leq\ldots\leq a_k\leq a_{k+1}=b$. Now $f$ is integrable on $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$. On each such interval, choose a partition $P_i$ so that $S(P_i)-s(P_i)<\epsilon$. Then take the union of all your partitions $P=P_0\cup\ldots\cup P_k$. For this partition
$$\begin{align}
S(P)-s(P)&=S(P_0)+S(P_1)+\ldots+S(P_k)-(s(P_0)+\ldots+s(P_k))\\
&=(S(P_0)-s(P_0))+\ldots+(S(P_k)-s(P_k))\\
&\leq k\epsilon \end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you explain how do I choose a partition so that $S(Pi)-s(Pi)<\epsilon$?

Comment: @JaVaPG By definition, $f$ is continuous on $[a_i,a_{i+1}]$. So $f$ is integrable on this interval. The definition of integrability is that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a partition $P$ such that $S(P)-s(P)<\epsilon$.